# Why isn't typescript complaining lack of return when inside else only?

Tags: typescript

In my test function, I tell TypeScript that this function should return a boolean.  But the return statement is only inside else.  Why is TypeScript not complaining?  This is TypeScript 3.9.7, using vscode.

```
public doSomeRandomeThing() {
  console.log('hello');
}

public test(val?: string): boolean {
  const someVar = '';
  if (someVar === '') {
    this.doSomeRandomeThing();
  } else {
    if (val) {
      this.doSomeRandomeThing();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Turn on strictNullChecks or strict

Comment: You code works as you expect with the default `tsconfig` settings: https://tsplay.dev/W445KW

Comment: @Evert You are exactly right.  Thanks!